# Programming-General: What are the 5 stages in which a source code is transformed to a executable file?

Tags: programming-languages

I receive this question in a test:

What are the 5 stages in which a source code is transformed to a executable file?

Comment: compiling, compiling, compiling, sword fighting, done. :p

Comment: 1. Compiling. 2. Googling on compiler errors. 3. Ask on stackoverflow about compiler errors. 4. Correcting errors. 5. Compiling. ;)

Comment: @Kenny, this needs to be an answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: @Guffa:  You forgot "realizing you're in an endless loop."

Answer (score 5):

The **five stages are bogus.**  [Standard ML of New Jersey](http://smlnj.org/), for example, was at one point a 33-pass compiler, going from source code to machine code (no textual assembly; it blasts machine code right into memory).  I doubt there are exactly five representations that the code goes through.  In the [lcc C compiler](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/lcc/) there are these representations:

- Unpreprocessed source
- Preprocessed source
- IR Dags
- Textual assembly
- Relocatable object code
- Executable binary

These days most other compilers translate source into abstract syntax, and in fact the designers of lcc said in retrospect that they wish they had used abstract-syntax trees.

This seems like one of those sad situations where you need to **find out what your instructor wants to hear and regurgitate it back.**  And don't take it too seriously.

Comment: +1 for "find out what your instructor wants to hear and regurgitate it back". Tongue planted firmly in cheek.

Answer (score 4):

There can not be fixed 5 steps. 
Depends on what language is the source code in and what compiler is used.

Answer (score 3):

One minute on google would have resolved your question

[Compiler is the magic word](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigmil/RevEng/ch02.html)

If your eyes can't find the right line :)

Compilation in general is split into roughly 5 stages:

Preprocessing, Parsing, Translation, Assembling, and Linking.